# How do I limit a user's permission in Sharepoint to a single survey

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, permissions

I have a user group set up in Sharepoint that has permission to access to a single site.  I would like to restrict this groups access futher to a single survey within that site.  Is there any way to set Sharepoint permissions to a more granular level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give access to only specific lists, views or pages using the Limited Access Permission Level

Go into the list or view that you want to give people access to, go to Settings --> List Settings --> Permissions for this List

You can then give direct rights to users that do not have access to any objects higher up in the hierarchy.