# Remove permissions on list item change in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, permissions

Is there any chance I can remove survey permissions on List item change?

Comment: You may wish to consider posting on the SharePoint SE: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "survey permission"? I don't think there is an explicit survey permission, but only the "Edit Item" permission.

In any case you can remove permissions on list item change by using Sharepoint event receiver. The Event Receiver you are looking for is the `ItemUpdated` receiver.

To get started with event receivers you can look at the following posts:

- [Delving into SharePoint 2007 Event Receivers](http://www.davehunter.co.uk/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=69)
- [Delving into SharePoint 2007 Event Receivers](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/Event%20Receivers.aspx)

To remove/edit permissions of specific list items you can check out [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513420/how-do-i-limit-a-users-permision-in-sharepoint-to-a-single-survey) [other](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2007/11/15/how-to-programmatically-set-permissions-on-files-folders-in-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx) [posts](http://www.csharpest.net/?p=74) here on SO and anywhere else ;-)